How to use gradle compileOnly dependencies at runtime also
I have a simple spring boot app with below gradle file. Gradle version used is 7.6.x
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootPlugin = 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin'
        springBootVersion = '2.4.5'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-gradle-plugin:1.3.2"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:gradle-processes:0.5.0"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'war'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: "org.springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin"

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-gradle-plugin', version: '2.4.5'
    compileOnly('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compileOnly('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compileOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compileOnly 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.15'
    //testRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
}

springBoot {
    mainClassName = 'com.example.DemoApplication'
}


jar {
    enabled = false
}
war {
    classpath = configurations.providedRuntime
}

openApi {
    apiDocsUrl.set("http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs")
    outputDir.set(file("$buildDir/api"))
    outputFileName.set("openapi.json")
    waitTimeInSeconds.set(100)
   //forkProperties.set("-Dlogging.level.root=DEBUG")
    //forkProperties.set("-Dspring.profiles.active=openapi")
}

I want to generate the war file on gradle clean build without any libs in it also, for the open api json generation it needs the dependencies at runtime in order to start the app and download the api-docs.
How can I achieve that without changing the dependency configuration so that my gradle generateOpenApiDocs task runs succcessfully by creating the openApi.json file as output?

What about having the dependencies defined in implementation configuration and just adjusting the war plugin to classpath = configurations.providedCompile?

I have tried that but the war gets generated with the lib under WEB-INF which we don't need
